# Angular 6: cannot macht routes (nested)

Tags: angular, nested-routes

I have this very simple project to test nested routing. The app-routes work, but not the children "cannot match any routes", says the error. Checked other answers but the versions made me confused. Here's what I have:

APP.MODULE.TS

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CountriesModule } from './countries/countries/countries.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdressComponent} from './adress/adress.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AdressComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, CountriesModule, RouterModule ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

App.Routing,Module.TS

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdressComponent } from './adress/adress.component';
import { CountriesComponent } from './countries/countries/countries.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdressComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'country',
    component: CountriesComponent
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Countries.Module (nested)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CountriesComponent } from './countries.component';
import { AddCountryComponent } from './add-country/add-country.component';
import { CountryListComponentComponent } from './country-list-component/country-list-component.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CountriesComponent,
    AddCountryComponent,
    CountryListComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule]
})
export class CountriesModule {}
```

Routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CountriesComponent } from './countries.component';
import { AddCountryComponent } from './add-country/add-country.component';
import { CountryListComponentComponent } from './country-list-component/country-list-component.component';

export const countryRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'country',
    component: CountriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddCountryComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'list',
        component: CountryListComponentComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(countryRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CountryRoutingModule {}
```

HTML (countries)

```
<a [routerLink]="['/country/list/']" routerLinkActive="active">List</a>
```

EDIT: @Maihan Nijat

```
The project in StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsj8qd
```

Comment: Remove the `country` route from the `AppRoutingModule` routes

Comment: use  path as  "country/list" in Routing and there is an extra "/" in your <a [routerLink]="['/country/list/']" routerLinkActive="active">List</a>

Comment: also use "redirectTo"

Comment: this path `<a [routerLink]="['country/list']" routerLinkActive="active">Country</a>
` dos not work either. It has to be a sctructural issue

Comment: How can I remove ountry from appModule? Its on the top level, its a parent route

Comment: and with this path `<a [routerLink]="['country/list']" routerLinkActive="active">Country</a>
` the error is something like `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'country/country/list'`

Comment: if that is the case use like this {
    path: '',
    component: CountriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'country/add',
        component: AddCountryComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'country/list',
        component: CountryListComponentComponent
      }
    ]
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184362/discussion-between-chethu-and-mellville).

Answer (score 0):

It should be just **`list`**, remove the last backslash from the routerLink

```
<a [routerLink]="['/country/list']
```

Comment: I don't think so...`<a [routerLink]="['/country/list']" routerLinkActive="active">Country</a>
` gives me the same error, Sajeetharan

Answer (score 0):

App Routing Modules:

Edit the path `app/countries.module#CountriesModule'` to match your path. Go through paths in the code before testing it.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'country', loadChildren: 'app/countries/countries/countries.module#CountriesModule'},
  {path: '', component: AdressComponent},
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Country Routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CountriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddCountryComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'list',
        component: CountryListComponentComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CountryRoutingModule {}

export const routedComponents = [
  CountriesComponent,
  CountryListComponentComponent,
  AddCountryComponent,
];
```

Country Module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...routedComponents],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, CountryRoutingModule],
})
export class CountriesModule {}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but with this change: `const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'country',
  loadChildren: 'app/countries.module#CountriesModule'
 },
  { path: '', component: AdressComponent },
];` i get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'app/countries.module'` Now Im lost :)

Comment: the error remains `Cannot find module 'app/countries/countries/countries.module'`....

Comment: @Mellville create your project here,so I help you https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Ok @Maihan, I will do it later, now I have to move, and thakns for your help!

Comment: the project is here: https://angular-jccrbc.stackblitz.io
Its a bit different, I cant see red lines, so everything is messed up - i just copyed and pasted